# What is wrong with my LINQ here? Doing what MSDN says, but

Tags: linq-to-xml

I'm trying to get an understanding of LINQ, and starting out on the MSDN page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb308960.aspx#xlinqoverview_topic2f

Here, it references some sample XML

```
<contacts>
  <contact>
    <name>Patrick Hines</name>
    <phone type="home">206-555-0144</phone>
    <phone type="work">425-555-0145</phone>
    <address>
      <street1>123 Main St</street1>
      <city>Mercer Island</city>
      <state>WA</state>
      <postal>68042</postal>
    </address>
    <netWorth>10</netWorth>
  </contact>
  <contact>...
```

and says that the following will pump out a list of "phone" elements:

```
XElement contacts = XElement.Load(@"C:\Projects\ALL_MY_PROJECTS\LINQ_Noodling\UI\Contacts.xml");
foreach (x in contact.Elements("phone")) {
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

like this:

```
<phone>206-555-0144</phone>
<phone>425-555-0145</phone>
```

Except it doesn't.  I get nothing whatever.  If I replace "phone" in the above with "contact" I get all the contacts (including "name" "phone" "address" and all the child elements), but that is it.  It wouldn't be the last time that MSDN provided misleading or incorrect information, but the info as presented *looks* correct and logical.

Comment: Have you tried replacing "phone" with "address" or "netWorth" and seeing what happens?

Comment: Well the code is looking for elements in the contacts file, which would be the `contact` level, not the phone level. What you want is one level down.

Comment: You are not following the MSDN example from top of the page to the bottom, you are jumping to a code snippet and using it out of context. Please read and following the examples from top to bottom and you should get it.

Comment: @Rodney, I did take it from top to bottom and nowhere did it indicate that it was angling for the second level.  It clearly is trying to jump to the second level without a ref to the first -- I may be unobservant, but not *that* unobservant..  @Anon., @Matti and @Femaref called it.

Comment: Just after the "Getting the children of an XML element" header it says, "For example, you might have the following XML loaded into an XElement called contact:", at which point it shows some XML with just a single contact. It's understandable that you missed it (I know I skipped right past it the first time, to find the point you were talking about), but it is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<phone>` is a child element of `<contact>`, *not* the root element. If you look at the MSDN examples, note that they're calling Elements on one particular contact element.

You can chain Elements calls* to get further children:

```
foreach(XElement x in contacts.Elements("contact").Elements("phone"))
```

---

*if we were being nitpicky, it's not really chaining the same function, but `IEnumerable<XObject>::Elements()` acts pretty much how we expect it to anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should pay more attention before claiming that something another person wrote is wrong.

The part in which they do

```
foreach (x in contact.Elements("phone")) {
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Is preceded by:

```
For example, you might have the following XML loaded into an XElement called contact:

<contact>
   Met in 2005.
   <name>Patrick Hines</name>
   <phone>206-555-0144</phone>
   <phone>425-555-0145</phone>
   <!--Avoid whenever possible-->
</contact>
```

And your XML file doesn't match that. `Elements` only finds *direct* children of the element. So using the XML file you provided, the correct way to access the phone numbers (of everyone in the file) would be

```
XElement contacts = XElement.Load(@"C:\Projects\ALL_MY_PROJECTS\LINQ_Noodling\UI\Contacts.xml");
foreach (x in contacts.Elements("contact").Elements("phone")) {
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I didn't claim that the MSDN information was incorrect or wrong in this instance, but that I had in times past found incorrect information there, and was wondering if this was another such case.  You're right, I clearly misunderstood the MSDN article.  But while I appreciate your response and gave it +1, I must gently suggest that you need to pay more attention to what is written before criticizing it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a child of a child of `contacts`. You'd have to do:

```
XElement contacts = XElement.Load(@"C:\Projects\ALL_MY_PROJECTS\LINQ_Noodling\UI\Contacts.xml");

foreach (x in contact.Elements("contact")) {
    Console.WriteLine(x.Element("phone"));
}
```

`contacts` is the root of the xml, `contact` is a child, and `phone` is a child of `contact`. The `x` in your loop is a `contact` node, on which you need to access its children.